# Linux kernel memset - what is the address

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

What is the address which memset works in kernel space? I suppose that it is kernel virtual address. So if I want to reprint some memory represented by `vm_area_struct` userspace virtual memory address I need to obtain corresponding `struct page *` areas and then do `kmap()` to get kernel virtual address.

Am i right?

Comment: How memset relate to this?

Comment: I can't undertand what address I have to push into memset routine to reprint physical memory region: userspace virtual address or kernel space virtual address. I assume the second one.